# How to compile ip_tables module family from the customer Linux kernel source code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables

I'm trying to build a customer Linux kernel (I modified the source code a bit). The version is 3.13.11 and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. However, when doing `make modules_install`, I find only a few modules are compiled and installed, which makes the module `ip_tables` does not work well:

```
$ modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe: FATAL: Module iptable_nat not found.
```

I can find this module in the original kernel repo:

```
/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter$ ls
arptable_filter.ko   ipt_CLUSTERIP.ko      nf_nat_ipv4.ko
arp_tables.ko        ipt_ECN.ko            nf_nat_pptp.ko
arpt_mangle.ko       ipt_MASQUERADE.ko     nf_nat_proto_gre.ko
iptable_filter.ko    ipt_REJECT.ko         nf_nat_snmp_basic.ko
iptable_mangle.ko    ipt_rpfilter.ko       nf_tables_arp.ko
iptable_nat.ko       ipt_SYNPROXY.ko       nf_tables_ipv4.ko
iptable_raw.ko       ipt_ULOG.ko           nft_chain_nat_ipv4.ko
iptable_security.ko  nf_conntrack_ipv4.ko  nft_chain_route_ipv4.ko
ip_tables.ko         nf_defrag_ipv4.ko     nft_reject_ipv4.ko
ipt_ah.ko            nf_nat_h323.ko
```

But in my kernel repo, I couldn't find them:

```
/lib/modules/3.13.11/kernel/net$ ls
bluetooth
```

I tried to use `make menuconfig` to enable the entries following this: http://blog.serverbuddies.com/enable-iptables-support-in-linux-kernel/. But I still got `iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table 'nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)`. If I understand correctly, this is caused by the module `iptable_nat` is not installed.

Any ideas to fix this?

Thank in advance!

Comment: According to the [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/Makefile?v=3.13#L42), module `iptable_nat` depends from `CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4` configuration option. Check (via `grep`ing `.config` file) that you have this option enabled. If not, find in `make menuconfig` how to enable it.

Comment: Thanks so much! You are right this seems to be the option for that module. I searched in the `.config` file but find nothing related - neither enabled nor disabled.  I have used `make menuconfig` to enable all entries under `Netfilter Xtables support (required for ip_tables)` and `IPv4 connection tracking support (required for NAT)` as http://blog.serverbuddies.com/enable-iptables-support-in-linux-kernel/ suggested. I'm a bit confused how to enable a single options with menuconfig now. I tried to add a single line for this option but failed.... Do you have any insight for this?

Comment: Configurator `make menuconfig` has mechanism for search options. Type `/` and follow instructions it shows.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Thank you! Yes I find the instruction and am trying to include all the dependencies now. Hopefully it will work.